# Color points scatter from .csv in order according to colormap

Tags: pgfplots, color, csv

I want to color these 10 points from the .csv the same colors as the corresponding colormap, in the order that they appear (i.e. completely independent of their x,y value). How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

% Define inferno colormap
\pgfplotsset{%
    colormap={inferno}{%
        rgb255=(0, 0, 4)
        rgb255=(12, 8, 38)
        rgb255=(36, 12, 79)
        rgb255=(66, 10, 104)
        rgb255=(93, 18, 110)
        rgb255=(120, 28, 109)
        rgb255=(147, 38, 103)
        rgb255=(174, 48, 92)
        rgb255=(199, 62, 76)
        rgb255=(221, 81, 58)
        rgb255=(237, 105, 37)
        rgb255=(248, 133, 15)
        rgb255=(252, 165, 10)
        rgb255=(250, 198, 45)
        rgb255=(242, 230, 97)
        rgb255=(252, 255, 164)
    }
}
    
\begin{document}

% Create CSV file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
z_1_real;z_1_imag
-3.0;0
-2.7;0
-2.4;0
-2.0;0
-1.8;0
-1.5;0
-1.2;0
-1.0;0
-0.6;0
-0.3;0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        width=60mm,
        xmin=-3.5,
        xmax=0.5,
        ymin=-0.5,
        ymax=0.5,
        colorbar horizontal,
        colormap name=inferno,
        colorbar sampled,
        colormap access=piecewise const,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=10,
        colorbar style={
            samples=11,
            xtick={0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5},
            xticklabels={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
            height=2mm,
            xtick align=outside,
            xtick pos=right,
            x tick label style={
                above,
                yshift=5mm,
                },
            x label style={
                above,
                yshift=9mm,
                },
            tick label style={above},
            tick style={
                color=black
            },
            at={(0,0.55)},
            anchor=current axis.north west
            }
        ] 
        \draw[draw=gray] (0,0) circle (1);
        \addplot[scatter, mark=*, only marks, mark options={scale=1, line width=1.5pt}] table [x=z_1_real, y=z_1_imag, col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: scatter_cmap]

**Wanted:**

[image: desired]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the point `meta=explicit symbolic`

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% Define inferno colormap
\pgfplotsset{%
    colormap={inferno}{%
        rgb255=(0, 0, 4)
        rgb255=(12, 8, 38)
        rgb255=(36, 12, 79)
        rgb255=(66, 10, 104)
        rgb255=(93, 18, 110)
        rgb255=(120, 28, 109)
        rgb255=(147, 38, 103)
        rgb255=(174, 48, 92)
        rgb255=(199, 62, 76)
        rgb255=(221, 81, 58)
        rgb255=(237, 105, 37)
        rgb255=(248, 133, 15)
        rgb255=(252, 165, 10)
        rgb255=(250, 198, 45)
        rgb255=(242, 230, 97)
        rgb255=(252, 255, 164)
    }
}

\begin{document}

% Create CSV file
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
z_1_real;z_1_imag;meta  % added column 'meta' for the order of colors
-3.0;0;0
-2.7;0;1
-2.4;0;2
-2.0;0;3
-1.8;0;4
-1.5;0;5
-1.2;0;6
-1.0;0;7
-0.6;0;8
-0.3;0;9
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        width=60mm,
        xmin=-3.5,
        xmax=0.5,
        ymin=-0.5,
        ymax=0.5,
        colorbar horizontal,
        colormap name=inferno,
        colorbar sampled,
        colormap access=piecewise const,
        point meta min=0,  %<= first point
        point meta max=9,  %<= Last point
        colorbar style={
            samples=10,  %<=number of points
            xtick={0, 1, ..., 9},  %<=meta values'
            xticklabels={1, 2, ..., 10},  %<=Poitn order
            height=2mm,
            xtick align=outside,
            xtick pos=right,
            x tick label style={
                above,
                yshift=5mm,
                },
            tick label style={above},
            tick style={
                color=black
            },
            at={(0,0.55)},
            anchor=current axis.north west
            }
        ] 
        \draw[draw=gray] (0,0) circle (1);
        \addplot[scatter, mark=*, only marks, mark options={scale=1, line width=1.5pt}, scatter src=explicit, point meta=\thisrow{meta}] table [x=z_1_real, y=z_1_imag, meta=meta, col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};  %<= use of point meta here
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I do seem to get 'attempt to get length of a nil value (local 'result')' error in my original file, although the results appear fine. Any idea why that is?